# How to inject javascript var into css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, electron

I want to predefine the position of the website shown inside my webview (electron). I want to add the left value dynamically . I have something like this :

```
var leftPos = -300px; // it is set dynamically

var webview = document.querySelector('webview');

webview.executeJavaScript("$('body').css('left', leftPos )"); //it cannot get the value of leftPos
```

but if leftPos is hardcoded this will work e.g: 
leftPos

```
webview.executeJavaScript("$('body').css('left', '-300px' )"); //works
```

The problem should be the parenthesis but I tried everything and I cannot seem to pass the leftPos value inside that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String concatenation:

```
webview.executeJavaScript("$('body').css('left', " + leftPos + " )");
// ----------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That'll work if `leftPos` just has a number in it (-300, which will be -300 pixels).

If `leftPos` is a *string* with `px` in it, you'll need `'` in there as well:

```
webview.executeJavaScript("$('body').css('left', '" + leftPos + "' )");
// ----------------------------------------------^---------------^
```